# Визуализация множественной регрессионной модели

Tags: r, визуализация, rstudio, ggplot2, регрессия

Построил линейную модель, включающую зависимую непрерывную переменную, 3 непрерывных предиктора, 2 дискретных (факторы с двумя градациями каждый), а также взаимодействие одного из этих непрерывных и одного дискретного предиктора. Хочу построить серию серию графиков, отражающих связь зависимой переменной с  предикторами, а также на одном из них визуализировать взаимодействие. В курсе учили изображать связь с наиболее важными предикторами при условии, что все остальные предикторы неизменны, например, их значения равны средним. Только как сделать неизменными факторы? Усреднить их, понятно, не получится, приравненными к нулю - тоже не принимает.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос довольно общий, поэтому и ответ получается такой же.

Простого и однозначного способа оценки взаимосвязи отдельно взятого предиктора с целевой переменной в рамках конкретной модели не существует. Есть целый ряд подходов, которые подробно рассмотрены в книге https://ema.drwhy.ai/ (в частности, см. разделы  Break-down Plots и Partial-dependence Profiles).

Comment: По нижеприведенной ссылке попытался максимально конкретизировать вопрос, включая  приведенный код и даже приблизительный формат графиков, которые хочу получить. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780361/plotting-multiple-linear-regression-including-continuous-and-discrete-predictors